# Updating the help center: What's on-topic?

Tags: discussion

This help center article about what's on topic could use a little love:

https://tor.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

If anyone wants to discuss what it should say here, or wants to make some modifications, that would be great.

Answer (score 1):

Here what comes first to my mind:

- Questions about how Tor works
- Installation of Tor or TorBrowserBundle
- Questions related to running and/or configuring Tor on different platforms and OSes
- Issues concerning using Tor, TorBrowserBundle, OrBot, etc
- Questions about Tor affiliated software
- Questions about ISPs regarding allowing and censoring Tor
- Linux distros or other software that is based around Tor, such as Tails, Whonix, etc
- Questions regarding Tor bridges and pluggable transports
- Questions related to Internet services or websites that can/cannot be accessed through Tor
- Questions about privacy and anonymity in Tor context

What should be considered off-topic:

- Questions and recommendation requests of particular hidden services
- Questions about privacy and anonymity that are not related to Tor
- Anything else not related to Tor

What's in between:

- Tor-related programming questions that need help in how to make a piece of code work with Tor or implement some of Tor functionalities, and questions about Tor libraries. Some lines should be drawn here to decide what's on-topic and what's not.